# Which type of conditional should I use?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

The meaning of my sentence is "**I didn't practice English a lot and that's why I don't know it well.**"

Which conditional should I use?

This one is 2nd conditional.

> If I practiced English more, I would know it much better.

And this one is mixed conditional(3rd conditional + 2nd conditional).

> If I had practiced English more, I would know it much better.

Comment: One talks about the present and future, while the other talks about the past and the present. Which you should use depends on the specific meaning you are trying to convey.

Comment: @Jason: Actually, the first sentence might be talking about the present and the present.

Comment: @PeterShor I suppose it's possible, but it seems somehow semantically wrong to me to think of it as present and present. (*If I [were practising] English more **today**, I would know it much better **today**.*) Still, just because I think it would be a bit nonsensical to interpret it that way doesn't mean it couldn't be …

Comment: @Jason: it doesn't seem wrong at all to me; *"If I were in the habit of practicing English more, I would know it much better today"* seems like a perfectly good interpretation of that sentence.

Comment: @PeterShor Your interpretation is a habitual present, mine is an immediate present. As the sentence is written, a book is open and a pens is lifted to a page. Since the specific activity hasn't ended in my interpretation, it's odd to mention a result. (It's possible, but simply strange.)